# Custom security trimming SharePoint FAST Search results

Tags: performance, sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, security-trimming

I have created a custom search security trimmer for SharePoint Search. Unfortunately it doesn"t work with SharePoint FAST Search.

Is there any way by which similar custom security trimming of FAST Search results can be achieved ?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is well known to Microsoft. My company has an open support request for it and other developers have noticed the same.

[Security Trimming Secrets](http://www.threewill.com/2011/03/security-trimming-secrets/)

I'm not aware of any workaround. All we can do is wait.

Comment: Thanks for referencing my blog.  Hopefully you have found it useful.

Comment: My understanding is that FAST wants to have "deep refiners" and exact counts on those refiners.  When you incorporate query time security trimming this is not possible.  Without FAST the refiners are not "deep".  The query only looks ahead to 50 or so results to give you the refining options.  I believe FAST will look at all results to determine what you can refine on.  With a security time security trimmer you do not want to look through all of the results because it is too expensive.

Comment: The problem is not related to the FAST refiners (navigators) - well not really. The problem is performing the security trimming **after** results have been fetched ([MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796226.aspx)), thus destroying refiner counts. Ideally - just like the OOTB access control works - the search query would be extended to check some special index field (docacl).